# yii cgridview How to disable button

Tags: gridview, yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I know `template` or `visible` attribute can make it display or not if I need to display the button but I just want to disable the button. How to make it work

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'customer-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
       'id',
       'first_name',
     ),
    'template'=>'{update}{delete}'
```

Comment: create a new column for your buttons instead of using `CButtonColumn`, it will be much easier then.

Comment: thanks @Criesto . I think your answer is much suitable for me

Answer (score 2):

Try `deleteButtonOptions` and `updateButtonOptions` of CColumnButton as

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'customer-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'first_name',
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
            'header' => 'Manage',
            'template' => '{update}{delete}',
            'deleteButtonOptions' => array(
                'disabled' => true
            ),
            'updateButtonOptions' => array(
                'disabled' => true
            )
        ),
    ),

));
```

Comment: it's one solution, it workes. but not perfect for me .

Answer (score 1):

**Disable View, Edit and Delete button.**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'auction-bid-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'name',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
              'template' => '',
        ),      
    ),  
));
```